# What is the proper workflow of starting a new project with grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

So i started using grunt, ran through some tutorials but somehow i haven't found an easy way of initialising a new project with all the predefined plugins in your default gruntfile.js?

So, yeah, i got that everytime you have to reinstall grunt locally with cd your-working-dir and then npm install grunt --save-dev?

Then i have my gruntfile.js which, i guess, i can copy and use just like my default grunt file? I guess the main question of mine is this: do i have to install each of grunt plugins manually whenever i start a new project?

for example if i have sass task in my gruntfile.js and when i start this new project i have to npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev every single time?

Comment: Check out the http://yeoman.io/ - it scaffolds projects for you.

Comment: Hmm, so as far as i understood i need to create a custom yeoman generator and then i would be able to "scaffold" new projects with all my predefined modules, files and folders with one command? Thats pretty cool.

Going to try this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-own-yeoman-generator--cms-20040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least several options, ordered by complexity ascending:

- Create your default projects on disk, and a shell script to automate the bootstrapping.
- Use Github, and create a default project that you can bootstrap with GIT on your box.
- Use Yeoman scaffolding, and create a custom yeoman generator as a NPM package.

Shell automation can apply to the second and third approach as well.

Yeoman, is def. the cool option, but also takes the most time, and requires more maintenance than the other options.